# Strange behavior with NVIDIA CUDA 4.1 RC2 and Parallel NSight 2.1

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu, nsight

I am having a strange problem debugging my CUDA code in Nsight 2.1.  I have two **global** functions that get called from my main.cu like so:

```
dim3 block(threadsPerBlock);
dim3 grid(numBlocks);
InitPhotons<<<grid,block>>>(devicerun,sources[i],1);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
MC<<<grid,block>>>(devicerun,sources[i],1);
```

I can hit breakpoints in InitPhotons successfully, and single step through that function.  However, I can only hit the first breakpoint I set in MC.  If I attempt to single step through the function (F10 in VS), the debugger behaves as if I had used the continue command (F5) and no longer hits breakpoints.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?  Does anyone have any ideas for a solution?

I am using Parallel NSight 2.1 with CUDA 4.1 RC2 in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.  I am compiling with the -G0 flag, and optimization is disabled.

Edit: The problem seems to be with the default size of Code patching memory.  I changed the Code patching memory factor from 2 to 4, and everything works fine (Nsight->Options->CUDA->Code patching memory factor).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a member of the Parallel Nsight team at NVIDIA. Unfortunately, this sounds like it could be a bug.

Is there any chance we could take a look at your project? Please contact me via email by filing a bug for the issue here: http://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/bugs/parallel-nsight-bug-reporting

I'll take a look at it ASAP.

Thanks!

Comment: After looking at it a bit more, it seems the problem was with the code patching memory.  The error occurred when I had Code patching memory factor set to 2.  With this increased to 4, I can debug normally.  I'll still file the bug report, as this could be something to pop up an error message.